# TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python

I'm new to coding and Python. Not sure where exactly I should be looking to fix this error.

```
from UIMap  import tomcat8LoginPage,tomcat8urls,competitors

class test_Competitors(unittest):

def setup(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("https://qa-tomcat8.ez-touch.net/acton/account/login.jsp")

def test_Compete(self):
    driver = self.driver
    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    ### Log-in and navigate to Competitors page ###
    self.fill_out_field\
        (10, driver.find_element_by_id\
            (tomcat8LoginPage ['usernameField']),'username2092')

    self.fill_out_field\
        (10, driver.find_element_by_id\
            (tomcat8LoginPage['passwordField']),'Password2092')

    self.click\
        (10, driver.find_element_by_id\
            (tomcat8LoginPage ['loginBtn']))

    driver.get(tomcat8urls ['newUIurl'])

    self. click\
        (10, driver.find_element_by_xpath\
            (competitors ['inboundMenu']))
```

Comment: self is also argument. BTW you need to forget your annoying \ at the end of the line. Parens work just fine over multiple lines, and \ will break if someone adds a whitespace after it. Using \ for line continuation is very much against best practices in Python

Comment: I mean self.method(a, b) has 3 arguments: self, a, and b.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i know how you got your error. But i have faced this error lot of times and to me looks like its the same. I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask but still would like to answer it.

Problem in your code:

You are trying to inherit from unittest which is a MODULE and not a CLASS.

For example :

```
>>> import unittest
>>> class A(unittest):
...     def A(self):
...        print("Something...")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
>>> 
>>>
```

This shows all the attributes of the module :

```
>>> dir(unittest)
['FunctionTestCase', 'TestCase', 'TestLoader', 'TestProgram', 'TestResult', 'TestSuite', 'TextTestRunner', '_CmpToKey', '_TextTestResult', '_WritelnDecorator', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__', '__metaclass__', '__name__', '__package__', '__unittest', '__version__', '_makeLoader', '_strclass', 'defaultTestLoader', 'findTestCases', 'getTestCaseNames', 'main', 'makeSuite', 'os', 'sys', 'time', 'traceback', 'types']
>>>
```

I guess you want to imherit a class like "TestCase" and not "unittest" itself.

Try help(unittest) in python inyterpreter and you will get to know a lot about unittest .

Here is a simple usage of unittest copied from the help :

```
class IntegerArithmenticTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def testAdd(self):  ## test method names begin 'test*'
        self.assertEquals((1 + 2), 3)
        self.assertEquals(0 + 1, 1)
    def testMultiply(self):
        self.assertEquals((0 * 10), 0)
        self.assertEquals((5 * 8), 40)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```